# Can't close server (nodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why I can't close the server by requesting localhost:13777/close in browser (it continues to accept new requests), but it will gracefully close on timeout 15000? Node version is 0.10.18. I fell into this problem, trying to use code example from docs on exceptions handling by domains (it was giving me 'Not running' error every time I secondly tried to request error page) and finally came to this code.

```
var server

server = require("http").createServer(function(req,res){

  if(req.url == "/close")
  {
    console.log("Closing server (no timeout)")

    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log("I'm the timeout")
    }, 5000);    

    server.close(function(){
      console.log("Server closed (no timeout)")
    })    

    res.end('closed');
  }
  else
  {
    res.end('ok');
  }

});

server.listen(13777,function(){console.log("Server listening")});

setTimeout(function(){

  console.log("Closing server (timeout 15000)")
  server.close(function(){console.log("Server closed (timeout 15000)")})

}, 15000);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server is still waiting on requests from the client.  The client is utilizing HTTP keep-alive.

I think you will find that while the existing client can make new requests (as the connection is already established), other clients won't be able to.

Answer (score 3):

Nodejs doesn't implement a complex service layer on top of `http.Server`.  By calling `server.close()` you are instructing the server to no longer accept any "new" connections.  When a HTTP `Connection:keep-alive` is issued the server will keep the socket open until the client terminates or the timeout is reached.  Additional clients will not be able to issue requests

The timeout can be changed using `server.setTimeout()` https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_settimeout_msecs_callback

Remember if a client has created a connection before the `close` event that connection can continually be used.

It seems that a lot of people do not like this current functionality but this issue has been open for quite a while:

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/2642

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers point out, connections may persist indefinitely and the call to `server.close()` will not truly terminate the server if any such connections exist.

We can write a simple wrapper function which attaches a `destroy` method to a given server that terminates all connections, and closes the server (thereby ensuring that the server ends nearly immediately!)

Given code like this:

```
let server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  // ...
});
      
later(() => server.close()); // Fails to reliably close the server!
```

We can define `destroyableServer` and use the following:

```
let destroyableServer = server => {
  
  // Track all connections so that we can end them if we want to destroy `server`
  
  let sockets = new Set();
  server.on('connection', socket => {
    sockets.add(socket);
    socket.once('close', () => sockets.delete(socket)); // Stop tracking closed sockets
  });
  server.destroy = () => {
    for (let socket of sockets) socket.destroy();
    sockets.clear();
    return new Promise((rsv, rjc) => server.close(err => err ? rjc(err) : rsv()));
  };
  return server;
  
};

let server = destroyableServer(http.createServer((req, res) => {
  // ...
}));
      
later(() => server.destroy()); // Reliably closes the server almost immediately!
```

Note the overhead of entering every unique `socket` object into a `Set`